# File upload failing in golang

Tags: file, go, upload, multipart

In my use case I am trying to upload a file to server in golang. I have the following html code,

```
<div class="form-input upload-file" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="file"name="file" id="file" />
    <input type="hidden"name="token" value="{{.}}" />
    <a href="/uploadfile/" data-toggle="tooltip" title="upload">
        <input type="button upload-video" class="btn btn-primary btn-filled btn-xs" value="upload" />
    </a>
</div>
```

And the server side,

```
func uploadHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // the FormFile function takes in the POST input id file
    file, header, err := r.FormFile("file")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, err)
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()

    out, err := os.Create("/tmp/uploadedfile")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Unable to create the file for writing. Check your write access privilege")
        return
    }
    defer out.Close()

    // write the content from POST to the file
    _, err = io.Copy(out, file)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, err)
    }

    fmt.Fprintf(w, "File uploaded successfully : ")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, header.Filename)
}
```

When I try to upload the file, I am getting `request Content-Type isn't multipart/form-data` error in server side.

Could anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest I have no idea how do you even get error as your HTML is not form. But I think you getting error because by default form is send as GET request while `multipart/form-data` should be send via POST. Here is example of minimal form which should work.

```
<form action="/uploadfile/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <input type="hidden"name="token" value="{{.}}" />
    <input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am trying to use this inside another form. so I tried that way. Is there any work around to use this inside another form? It would be very helpful

Comment: @DineshAppavoo Form inside form?

Comment: looks like it is not possible [nest-forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms). I tried, the original form is getting collapsed. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: @DineshAppavoo only one "workaround" that I can imagine is send files via AJAX and put their IDs into "parent" form. But I can't understand why do you need nested form at all if you can just send one with fields and files.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you must include the header that contains the content type.

```
req.Header.Add("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())
```

This is included in the [`mime/multipart`](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/) package.

For a working example please check [this](https://matt.aimonetti.net/posts/2013/07/01/golang-multipart-file-upload-example/) blog post.

Comment: He is not trying to send form from Go app. He can't get HTML form data in his Go app.

Comment: Yes, and this is the reason why he's receiving the above error.

Comment: His Go code perfectly works with proper HTML form. And your link is about sending data from Go to remote service.